# "Feel safe at the thought of" or "in the thought of'?

Tags: phrases

I think it's "at" but I'm writing it as a part of a poem, so "in" feels better but I don't want it to sound wrong either. Basically the poet feels safe when she thinks about how she would be able to have a rested sleep because someone gave her a sense of security. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can feel safe "in" a place, "with" a person, or "at" the thought of something.

She felt safe in bed.
She felt safe with her mother in the house.
She felt safe at the thought of mother in the house.
She felt safe at the thought of the door being locked.